# CertificateException when testing with arquillian on glassfish-remote

Tags: glassfish, jboss-arquillian

When trying to run tests with arquillian with adminHttps option set to true, got an exception:

Could not connect to DAS on: (...) | java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not connect to DAS on: (...) | java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.CommonGlassFishManager.start(CommonGlassFishManager.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.remote_3_1.GlassFishRestDeployableContainer.start(GlassFishRestDeployableContainer.java:59)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)

The examples which I found were without ssl turned on.
I think that I should import a certificate, but can't find how or if it's realy that problem. Any idea? Thanks for sugestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by certificate. When deploying to another server you should import certificate from that server into current machine (when usins self-signed certificates)

Comment: Hello. Can you show how you imported the certificate please?

Comment: I'm afraid not :( I don't remember it now, and have no access to that knowledge...

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the accepted answer shows that this problem was due to the use of the containers self signed certificate, it doesn't explain how the problem can be overcome. Hopefully this answer will help anyone having the same problem.

You can import the containers self signed certificate into a keystore using the following command:

`keytool -import -alias glassfish -file mycert.cer -keystore truststore.jks -storepass changeit`

Change `mycert.cer` to the location of the certificate file

Change `truststore.jks` to the location of the keystore you want to use to store the certificate. This can either be a new keystore or an existing one. The `storepass` parameter is the password for the keystore. If you are using an existing keystore then you will need to specify the password associated with the keystore.

Once you have imported the self signed certificate into the keystore you need to tell the JVM running Arquillian to use the keystore. This can be done by setting the system parameter `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` to the location of the keystore. For example `javax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks`

Comment: where do I find mycert.cer in glassfish 4.1 directory?

Comment: mycert.cer is just the name the certificate file I used in this example. Instead you should use the name of the certificate file that has been signed by your certificate authority. This file doesn't need to be in the glassfish directory it just needs to be somewhere that is accessible by the keytool utility.

Comment: Ok, the issue is that I'm using the self-signed certificate that comes bundled in glassfish, but I found it in the domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks store.

Comment: Can ur explain how to fix this problem more carefully, I use IDEA. I take keystore from my glassfish remote server and add to Arquillian container settings -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="e:\keystore.jks" and add to run configuration of arquillian junit the same option but error still exitst